# Why can't xarray find this variable?

Tags: rasterio, rioxarray

I am very new to rasterio (about 20 minutes at this point). I am only trying to open a GRIB2 file and write to a GeoTIFF. I have installed all needed dependencies for reading GRIB files as well as writing GeoTIFF. For some reason, I am getting an error when trying to output.

The GRIB2 file can be downloaded  [here from Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10V8mcsmiE1ldOQECoiglGA-gIcjQrbFF/view?usp=sharing).

My code to do this is :

```
import rioxarray
import xarray

xds = xarray.open_dataset('MRMS_ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude_00.50_20211212-172838.grib2')
xds["ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude5km_altitude_above_msl"].rio.to_raster('output.tif')
```

Here is my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 1395, in _construct_dataarray
    variable = self._variables[name]
KeyError: 'ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude5km_altitude_above_msl'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\main\download\MRMS\_TEST\batshit.py", line 10, in <module>
    xds["ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude5km_altitude_above_msl"].rio.to_raster('BATSHIT.tif')
  File "C:\Users\David\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 1499, in __getitem__
    return self._construct_dataarray(key)
  File "C:\Users\David\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 1397, in _construct_dataarray
    _, name, variable = _get_virtual_variable(
  File "C:\Users\David\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\dataset.py", line 170, in _get_virtual_variable
    ref_var = variables[ref_name]
KeyError: 'ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude5km_altitude_above_msl'
```

I am seeing "KeyError" so I am thinking I have the variable name wrong. I had found that variable name using two different external viewers. I used Panoply and gdalinfo to look at the variable names, and also found ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude (gives the same error). There doesn't seem to be any combination that works.

Am I on the right track thinking it's a variable name issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gdalinfo` shows just a single band raster:

```
Driver: GRIB/GRIdded Binary (.grb, .grb2)
Files: MRMS_ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude_00.50_20211212-172838.grib2
Size is 7000, 3500
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unnamed",
        ELLIPSOID["Spheroid imported from GRIB file",6378160,298.253916296469,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-129.999999999857124,54.999999999857103)
Pixel Size = (0.009999999714245,-0.009999999714204)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-130.0000000,  55.0000000) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-130.0000000,  20.0000010) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( -60.0000020,  55.0000000) ( 60d 0' 0.01"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( -60.0000020,  20.0000010) ( 60d 0' 0.01"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      ( -95.0000010,  37.5000005) ( 95d 0' 0.00"W, 37d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=7000x1 Type=Float64, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = 500[m] GPML="Specific altitude above mean sea level"
  Metadata:
    GRIB_COMMENT=ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude [dBZ]
    GRIB_DISCIPLINE=209
    GRIB_ELEMENT=ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude
    GRIB_FORECAST_SECONDS=0
    GRIB_IDS=CENTER=161(US-OAR) SUBCENTER=0 MASTER_TABLE=255 LOCAL_TABLE=1 SIGNF_REF_TIME=3(Observation_time) REF_TIME=2021-12-12T17:28:38Z PROD_STATUS=2(Research) TYPE=7(Processed_radar_observations)
    GRIB_PDS_PDTN=0
    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_ASSEMBLED_VALUES=3 57 8 0 97 0 0 0 0 102 0 500 255 1 0
    GRIB_PDS_TEMPLATE_NUMBERS=3 57 8 0 97 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 102 0 0 0 1 244 255 1 0 0 0 0
    GRIB_REF_TIME=1639330118
    GRIB_SHORT_NAME=500-GPML
    GRIB_UNIT=[dBZ]
    GRIB_VALID_TIME=1639330118
```

The following seems to work:

```
import rioxarray
import xarray

xds = xarray.open_dataset('/tmp/MRMS_ReflectivityAtLowestAltitude_00.50_20211212-172838.grib2')
xds.rio.to_raster('output.tif')
```